# TensorFlow: Couldn't understand the error mentioned below

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

My code attempts to take different files as input and predict their language. This is the error I am getting every time I run the main file. At first, I thought it was a problem with the output path but so far it doesn't seem like that's the problem as I have gone through all the code files I have written and checked all the paths. And now I am unable to infer what this error actually means. Please help.

```
2022-11-25 16:53:52.060639: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/forward_type_inference.cc:332] Type inference failed. This indicates an invalid graph that escaped type checking. Error message: INVALID_ARGUMENT: expected compatible input types, but input 1:
type_id: TFT_OPTIONAL
args {
  type_id: TFT_PRODUCT
  args {
    type_id: TFT_TENSOR
    args {
      type_id: TFT_INT64
    }
  }
}
 is neither a subtype nor a supertype of the combined inputs preceding it:
type_id: TFT_OPTIONAL
args {
  type_id: TFT_PRODUCT
  args {
    type_id: TFT_TENSOR
    args {
      type_id: TFT_INT32
    }
  }
}

        while inferring type of node 'dnn/zero_fraction/cond/output/_18'
2022-11-25 16:53:54.402348: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1780] OP_REQUIRES failed at save_restore_v2_ops.cc:112 : NOT_FOUND: Failed to create a NewWriteableFile: C:/Users/vs889/Desktop/project/outputs\model.ckpt-0_temp\part-00000-of-00001.data-00000-of-00001.tempstate6886965226105612622 : The system cannot find the path specified.
; No such process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vs889\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1378, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\vs889\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1361, in _run_fn
    return self._call_tf_sessionrun(options, feed_dict, fetch_list,
  File "C:\Users\vs889\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1454, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    return tf_session.TF_SessionRun_wrapper(self._session, options, feed_dict,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Failed to create a NewWriteableFile: C:/Users/vs889/Desktop/project/outputs\model.ckpt-0_temp\part-00000-of-00001.data-00000-of-00001.tempstate6886965226105612622 : The system cannot find the path specified.
; No such process
         [[{{node save/SaveV2}}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your way of naming files and paths makes windows unable to recognize the file location. You can test by running on linux. You should agree to use "\" on Windows and avoid the "-" sign.

Comment: It is not a answer,  but a suggestion. Please use the comments for suggestion or discussions of the question itself. Only post answer when it is clear solution.
You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.